# Return documents Not matching all the values in array Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I have bunch of document's with fields like

```
user.userDatas.user_roles[1,2,3]
user.userDatas.user_roles[1,2,3,4,5]
user.userDatas.user_roles[1,3,4,5]
```

i have to make sure all the documents have values[1,2,3] in it, if not return the documents which doesn't have any one of the three values in it.
in the above example it should return [1,3,4,5] since 2 is missing in it.

i have tried this but it only returns the records matching 1,2,3 but i need the records doesn't have any of these 3.

```
  {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user.userDatas.user_roles": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user.userDatas.user_roles": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user.userDatas.user_roles": 3
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement :

**You need all the documents to have all 3 values, if not return the documents which don't have any one of the three values in them.**

You can use a combination of [`must` and `must_not` clause](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), to achieve your required results.

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "user.userDatas.user_roles": [
        5,
        4,
        6
    ]
}

{
    "user.userDatas.user_roles": [
        1,
        2,
        6
    ]
}

{
    "user.userDatas.user_roles": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "user.userDatas.user_roles": 1
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "user.userDatas.user_roles": 2
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "user.userDatas.user_roles": 3
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                 {
                    "bool": {
                        "must_not": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "user.userDatas.user_roles": 1
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "user.userDatas.user_roles": 2
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "user.userDatas.user_roles": 3
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Results:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "72974292",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 3.0,
                "_source": {
                    "user.userDatas.user_roles": [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "72974292",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "user.userDatas.user_roles": [
                        5,
                        4,
                        6
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks EScoder, it still returns all the documents when i tested with including some fuzzy number